# Why does Chrome try to download/save xml file served from gatsby on localhost, rather than display in browser if '.xml' suffix missing from filename?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, xml

This is a question about how a web server handles requests for XML files, depending on if the file has a '.xml' suff
I'm working with [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/). Developing on localhost.

I have an xml file/resource that gets served up by gatsby (i.e. using either `gatsby develop` or `gatsby serve`)

If I name the file something like `my-xml-file.xml` and then navigate to it in the browser (Chrome), via `http://localhost:8000/my-xml-file.xml`, then all is fine. Chrome loads/displays this in the browser.

However, if I rename the file to just `my-xml-file`, i.e. remove the '.xml' suffix from the file name, then when I try to navigate to it in the browser (Chrome), via `http://localhost:8000/my-xml-file`, then Chrome doesn't load/display it. Instead, in this scenario, Chrome opens a Save As dialogue window.

Any ideas what is going on here?

The reason why this confuses me is if I go to other locations on the web which I know are xml files, that are served without the '.xml' suffix, Chrome gladly loads/displays these in the browser.

For example:

- http://acme.libsyn.com/rss
- http://aboutradio.org/feed/
- http://bigband.rnn.libsynpro.com/rss

Chrome loads/displays these URLs directly in the browser

Why is the behaviour different for me when I serve an xml file without the .xml suffix in the filename compared to when other sites do it, like the examples above?

---

Things I have tried so far to figure this out.

- Serve the file locally using /my-xml-file.xml, open in Chrome

  - result: Chrome loads/displays file in browser window
- Serve the file locally using /my-xml-file, open in Chrome

  - result: Chrome opens save-as dialog
- Rename the file and serve as /my-xml-file.rss, open in Chrome

  - result: Chrome loads/displays file in browser window
- Serve the file locally using /my-xml-file.xml, open in Edge

  - result: Edge loads/displays file in browser window
- Serve the file locally using /my-xml-file, open in Edge

  - result: Edge loads/displays file in browser window
- Searched through StackOverflow for similar issues. Found the following (but none seem to match this issue specifically

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952514/how-to-force-open-links-in-chrome-not-download-them
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026466/open-with-chrome-instead-of-download-it
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069386/make-a-file-open-in-browser-instead-of-downloading-it-using-chrome-firebox
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006188/browsers-try-to-download-html-file-instead-of-opening
  - https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2263322?hl=en
- Checked the response header from my local example and compared it with other examples above. There is something that caught my eye... the value in the response for `Content-type` differs...

  - From my localhost: `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`
  - From the other examples:
  - [a)](http://acme.libsyn.com/rss): `content-type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8`
  - [b)](http://aboutradio.org/feed/): `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`
  - [c)](http://bigband.rnn.libsynpro.com/rss): `content-type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Your eyes are correct. You need to serve the correct content type (which is not octet-stream).

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill, the confirmation is much appreciated.

Curiously (but unimportant), I wonder why the Edge browser was able to comprehend that the file without the '.xml' suffix was actually xml content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer based on my investigation into the response header. *Thanks for confirming it [David Postill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill)*

The value for content-type should be set appropriately for an xml resource.

On my localhost, the file without the '.xml' suffix in the name was being served as application/octet-stream.

It should probably be served as something like application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8 or possibly application/xml.

Haven't had a chance to confirm this yet, will report back when I do.